# SQL Trigger on view to insert to table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to setup an insert trigger on a view like the one below:

```
CREATE view [dbo].[PYC_ServiceAppointments] AS   
   SELECT 
      e.epUR as 'ClientUR',  
      codeDescription as 'Category',  
      s.serName as 'Service',  
      a.OccurrenceDate as 'StartDate',   
      a.EndDate as 'EndDate',   
      a.StartTime as 'StartTime',   
      a.EndTime as 'EndTime',   
      a.Confirmed as 'ServiceStatus', 
      a.Note as 'Note'   
   FROM  
      [ServiceAppointmentViewBase] a  
   INNER JOIN 
      Episode e ON e.cid = a.ClientID AND e.epRecent = '1' 
   INNER JOIN 
      [Service] s ON s.serID = a.ServiceID 
   LEFT JOIN 
      Codes c ON s.sCatCode = c.codecode AND c.codetype = 'SVC'
```

I'm using the below table as the table where the data is to be inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceAppointments]
(     
    [SID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,    
    [ClientUR] [varchar](50) NULL,      
    [Category] [varchar](150) NULL,         
    [Service] [varchar](60) NULL,     
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,      
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,       
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,     
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,  
    [ServiceStatus] [bit] NULL,     
    [Note] [text] NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SID] ASC)    
      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

And this is the trigger I'm attempting to use to perform an insert:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Service]
 ON [PYC].[dbo].[PYC_ServiceAppointments]
 INSTEAD OF INSERT
 AS 
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;

    INSERT INTO PYC.dbo.ServiceAppointments 
               ( 
                ClientUR,
                Category,
                [Service],
                StartDate,
                EndDate,-- = ISNULL(Getdate(), CurrentValues.EndDate)),
                StartTime,
                EndTime,
                ServiceStatus,
                Note )
        SELECT  
           b.ClientUR, b.Category, b.[service], b.StartDate, b.EndDate, 
           b.StartTime, b.EndTime, b.ServiceStatus, b.Note
        FROM    
           Inserted b   
END
```

The database that stores the data doesn't have a unique ID against the table, so what I'm trying to accomplish is when an entry is added into the database and the requirements are met in the view so it is populated with this entry that it will fire the trigger and add this row to the table with the SID (PK) assigning an id for that row.

I've tried the same trigger on a test table that contains the same columns as the designated table and when entry is added to the table the trigger fires and adds the row to the other table.

I'm fairly new to using triggers so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: OK - so you've shown us your whole setup - and the **question** is?? Does this not work, i.e. give you an error? If so: *what* error?? Or what else is wrong? Everything seems to be in order, at first glance...

Comment: Why do you have `SET ROWCOUNT 0;`?? As far as I understand this means no rows will ever be processed.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `To set this option off so that all rows are returned, specify SET ROWCOUNT 0.` [SET ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)

Comment: Cool I learnt something new today.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly the problem is that your trigger doesn't work if you insert data into `ServiceAppointmentViewBase` table. It is the correct behaviour. Your trigger is defined on a view so it will be fired only if you insert data through this view. It is not fired if data are inserted directly into a table without using the view `PYC_ServiceAppointments`. Of course, to insert data through a view it must be updatable or as marc_s pointed the instead of trigger must exist on this view (as in your case).

Comment: *to insert data through a view it must be updatable* - or have an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, as the OP is doing ...

Comment: @marc_s - You are completely right but it doesn't change the fact that this trigger will not be fired if data are inserted directly into the underlying table.

Comment: Absolutely - I had missed that statement in the OP's question (and I was blindly assuming that if he set up a trigger *on the view*, of course he would be inserting data *into the view*.....)

Comment: @MichałKomorowski just to clarify my issue, when data is added to the underlying tables which then populates a row into my view the trigger isn't fired to add this row to my custom table. So what your saying is that since the data isn't technically being added to the view its being added to the underlying table it wont fire the insert statement?

Comment: @TimPartridge - It is exactly what I meant.